# Coordinates from 3DS Max to XNA 3.5

Tags: xna, c#, coordinates, 3dsmax

My problem is this. I have a simple box made in 3DS Max 2009, the Box is 10x10x10. I've tried to load it on XNA and traslate the camera for 15 units, but I can seem to find the values needed to see the box properly. Can anyone point me to a good resource where I can find some good introduction to XNA coordinate system and how is a simple box made in 3DS Max imported properly

Best regards,
David

Comment: There's no such thing as XNA 3.5. There's XNA 3.1 and XNA 4.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203910.aspx):

> The XNA Framework uses a
>   [right-handed coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#In_three_dimensions),
>   with the positive z-axis pointing
>   toward the observer when the positive
>   x-axis is pointing to the right, and
>   the positive y-axis is pointing up.

[Here is a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h5gmTpvlFZI) on how to export animated 3d meshes from 3DS Max to XNA, using [kW X-port](http://www.kwxport.org/), which is a quick and easy way of exporting 3d meshes as DirectX .x model files and loading them into XNA using the SkinnedModelProcessor.

Comment: Using skinning for such a simple model seems an overkill for me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply the bone transforms to the model before drawing it. Check the "Draw the model" section in the following page for a example of what you need to do:

http://www.toymaker.info/Games/XNA/html/xna_models.html